# How to clear a UICollectionViewCell on reload?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, reload

I have an issue where the data presented in a UICollectionView overwrites the label and the cell view is not getting cleared.

This image shows the issue,

IE:

[image: UICollectionViewCell data is not getting cleared]

My UICollectionViewCell which is constructed like so;

```
// in viewDidLoad
self.playerHUDCollectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifer)

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell:UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifer, for: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
    let arr = UINib(nibName: "EYPlayerHUDView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)
    let view = arr[0] as! EYPlayerHUDView
    cell.contentView.addSubview(view)
    if let allPlayers = self.allPlayers
    {
        let player:EYPlayer = allPlayers[indexPath.row]
        view.updatePlayerHUD(player: player)
    }
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
    return cell
}
```

I use a view to display in the cell.

I tried removing all the cell's subchildren in the `cellForItemAt` but it appears to remove all the subviews.

I would like to know how do I clear the `UICollectionViewCell` so labels and other info on the `UICollectionViewCell` is not dirty like the example above.

Many thanks

Comment: Answer is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33940252/duplicate-data-is-loading-when-i-scroll-the-uicollectionview/33940874#33940874

Comment: Your answer helped. Although the code was in Objective C; I was able to amend and update it for my requirements!

Comment: override [prepareForResure](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionreusableview/1620141-prepareforreuse) method in your custom cell class and add the desired clean up.

Comment: But there isn't a custom cell class.  Consider; the collection view cell is empty and doesn't do anything except add a subview.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `prepareForReuse` method in your custom cell class, something like this:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    //hide or reset anything you want hereafter, for example
    label.isHidden = true
}
```

in your `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, instantiate your custom cell:

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "myCellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! CustomViewCell
```

Then, always in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, setup your items visibility/values

Comment: In what file do I put the prepareForReuse? If I put it in my UICollectionViewController it will complain that the function does not override any method in superclass.       There is no CustomViewCell; its just a standard UICollectionViewCell

Comment: You should create a CustomCell e.g: class MyCustomCell: UICollectionViewCell. This is a best approach when you create cells for both CollectionViews and TableViews. Of course it depends on how much you want to customize your cell. See this [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/136159/uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started)

Comment: It works.  Many thanks.  Accepted your answer.   I removed the subviews I required in the prepareForReuse function

Comment: Perfect! Glad it helped you!

Answer (score 4):

```
//cell = UICollectionViewCell
for subview in cell.contentView.subviews {
     // you can place "if" condition to remove image view, labels, etc.
     //it will remove subviews of cell's content view
     subview.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`UICollectionViewCell`s are reused to avoid instantiations, to optimize the performance. If you are scrolling and a cell becomes invisible, the same object is used again (`dequeueReusableCell`) and a new *content* is set in `cellForItemAt`...

As mentioned in the previous answers, before reusing the cell, `prepareForReuse()` is called on the cell. So you can overrride `prepareForReuse()` and do whatever preparation you need to do.

You are however creating and adding a new `EYPlayerHUDView` to the cell on every reuse, so your cell becomes full of stacked `EYPlayerHUDView`s.

To avoid this, subclass `UICollectionViewCell` and make the `EYPlayerHUDView` a property of your custom cell (I recommend to use a `XIB`):

```
class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var player:EYPlayerHUDView!

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        // stop your player here
        // set your label text = ""
    }
}
```

After doing so, you can update the `EYPlayerHUDView` in `cellForItemAt` without instantiating it and without adding it as new view:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifer, for: indexPath) as? MyCell else {
        return nil
    }

    if let allPlayers = self.allPlayers {
        let player:EYPlayer = allPlayers[indexPath.row]
        cell.player.updatePlayerHUD(player: player)
    }

    return cell
}
```

(Code untested)

Comment: When overriding `prepareForReuse`, super should be called. I'm not the downvoter btw :)

Comment: @AhmadF Correct. Thx, Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Make custom UICollectionView class and implement prepareForReuse to clear the content if needed.